# android, save view image as png file

Tags: android, bitmap

I was expecting the code below to save an image to my local sdcard but when I run the app and trigger the saveCanvasImage() method it's not doing so. When I look in the LogCat I can find a System.err entry. The text says:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/drawPic1.png: open failed: EACCES (permission denied)

I thought this would create a new png file and save it in the directory. I'm obviously wrong. What can I change here to make it work?

```
public void saveCanvasImage() {

    Log.d("bitmap","strm");
    tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bm = tv.getDrawingCache();

    File fPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File f = null;
    f = new File(fPath, "drawPic1.png");

    try {
    FileOutputStream strm = new FileOutputStream(f);
    bm.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, strm);
    strm.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: did you add the write permission to the manifest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you put permission ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Excellent. That's what it was. But it's saving with a black background when the background is white on the device's screen.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you have added this permission to write to external storage

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following permission in your project's Manifest file permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to create a new file !
use this instead and set permission in manifest:

```
public void saveCanvasImage(Bitmap b) {

     File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/img.png");

     f.createNewFile();  // your mistake was at here      

     try {

     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

     b.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);

     fos.flush();

     fos.close();

     }catch (IOException e){

         e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
```

and the permission :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Hi Soroush. f.createNewFile doesn't seem to be necessary. I'm getting a png file in the relevant directory but it's saving with a black background which makes it not visible. What might be causing that?

Comment: Hi acl77 ,f.createNewFile is important because system want a file to put bitmap in it. you can test it and see

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
Bitmap bbicon;

bbicon=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bannerd10);
//ByteArrayOutputStream baosicon = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//bbicon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,0, baosicon);
//bicon=baosicon.toByteArray();

String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
OutputStream outStream = null;
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "er.PNG");
try {
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bbicon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
    outStream.flush();
    outStream.close();
} catch(Exception e) {

}
```

along with permissions.